# ceiling date in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I was using ceiling_date when I saw that it was behaving in a way inconsistent with floor_date. For example,

```
> floor_date(as.Date("05/10/2020","%m/%d/%Y"),unit="week",week_start=7)
[1] "2020-05-10"
> ceiling_date(as.Date("05/10/2020","%m/%d/%Y"),unit="week",week_start=7)
[1] "2020-05-17"
```

But `floor(5)=ceiling(5)=5` in R.

One has to set `change_on_boundary = False` in the ceiling_date function to make it behave like floor_date, but I think this should be the default behavior. I read up on the rationale behind having ceiling_date behave the way it does above, and it did not make sense to me. In fact, there was a time when what I think should be default behavior was indeed the default behavior. Please see my comments in italics below against the documentation.

change_on_boundary
If NULL (the default) don't change instants on the boundary (ceiling_date(ymd_hms('2000-01-01 00:00:00')) is 2000-01-01 00:00:00), but round up Date objects to the next boundary (ceiling_date(ymd("2000-01-01"), "month") is "2000-02-01"). When TRUE, instants on the boundary are rounded up to the next boundary. When FALSE, date-time on the boundary are never rounded up (this was the default for lubridate prior to v1.6.0. See section Rounding Up Date Objects below for more details.    <- *So there was a time when what I indicated should be default behavior was default behavior.*

By default rounding up Date objects follows 3 steps:

Convert to an instant representing lower bound of the Date: 2000-01-01 –> 2000-01-01 00:00:00

Round up to the next closest rounding unit boundary. For example, if the rounding unit is month then next closest boundary of 2000-01-01 is 2000-02-01 00:00:00.

The motivation for this is that the "partial" 2000-01-01 is conceptually an interval (2000-01-01 00:00:00 – 2000-01-02 00:00:00) and the day hasn't started clocking yet at the exact boundary 00:00:00. Thus, it seems wrong to round up a day to its lower boundary.

<-*I don't follow what "and the day hasn't started clocking yet at the exact boundary 00:00:00" means, and how and why " 2000-01-01 is conceptually an interval (2000-01-01 00:00:00 – 2000-01-02 00:00:00) " is relevant.
   Even if 5/10/2020 is considered as a whole day its ceiling date should, for unit=week and week_start=7, still be 5/10/2020 because ceiling_date(as.Date("05/10/2020","%m/%d/%Y"),unit=week and week_start=7) should return the earliest Sunday no earlier than 5/10/2020. And this day is clearly 5/10/2020. It is not 5/17/2020.*

Can someone weigh in on this?

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're saying, but I do see what they mean in the documentation as well.

I think the easiest way to illustrate this is to imagine someone telling you "happy Monday!" You would think that what they imply is that *Monday has already started*, right? Therefore, "Monday" loosely refers to the time period between Monday and Tuesday. If you think of days of a week on a real line and let the integers 1 to 7 represent days Monday to Sunday, then what the documentation is trying to say is that Monday loosely refers to the interval (1, 2), Tuesday loosely refers to the interval (2, 3), and so on. So basically you wanna think of a date as an instant that's strictly between that date and the next date. Thus it's not entirely illogical that they make the default behavior of rounding up dates the way they do.